# Bar graph with elements from the document

Tags: pgfplots, counters

In my document, I define some *elements* which all have a number (from 1 for the first to n for the last one) and a level (1, 2 or 3).

At the end of the document, I'd like to create a bar-graph with values coming from the number of elements and there level. The name of X values should be the title of the subsections the elements are set.

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\newcounter{numOfElem}

\newcommand{\elem}[2]{
    \stepcounter{numOfElem}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{6cm}|c|}
    \hline 
    E\thenumOfElem & #1 & #2 \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

First section.

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{X value 1}

This subsection title will be the first X value in the graph

\elem{First elem of level 1}{1}

\elem{Another elem of level 3}{3}

\subsection{X value 2}

This subsection's title will be the second X value in the graph.

\elem{Other elem of level 2}{2}

\elem{Other elem of level 3}{3}

\elem{Other elem of level 1}{1}

\elem{A last elem of level 1}{1}

\subsection{Other X value}

This subsection's title will be the second X value in the graph.

\elem{Other elem of level 1}{1}

\elem{Other elem of level 2}{2}

\elem{A last elem of level 3}{3}

\section{Final result}

There are \thenumOfElem~in the document.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#Elements},
    symbolic x coords={X value 1, X value 2, Other X value},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style = {rotate = 90},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(X value 1,1) (X value 2,2) (Other X value,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(X value 1,0) (X value 2,1) (Other X value,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(X value 1,1) (X value 2,1) (Other X value,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need your help to define the best *latex* way to do this.

Speaking shortly, I need to have a variable `symbolic x coords={X value 1, X value 2, Other X value},` and `\addplot coordinates {(X value 1,1) (X value 2,2) (Other X value,1)};` lines.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't get this actually. What shall the bar plot show? A distribution of levels?

Comment: The bar plot shows a distribution of levels of different elements. The declarations of the elements (name and level) is spread along subsections of the document. I want to summarize all the elements in a bar graph.

Comment: And this shall be done automatically?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to have a \bargraph command to do it at the end of the document.